# How to use IloCplex::addMIPStart in C++ API

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to use `IloCplex::addMIPStart` in C++ CPLEX Concert technology as follows:

```
IloCplex::MIPStartEffort effort = CPX_MIPSTART_SOLVEFIXED ;
cplex.addMIPStart(Y, Y_VAL,effort);
```

Unfortunately I face with the following error:
[image]

I have also tried writing `IloCplex::MIPStartEffort effort = MIPStartSolveFixed ;` but then it says `identifier "MIPStartSolveFixed" is undefined`.

According to

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloCplex.html#method_addMIPStart

and

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/enumerations/IloCplex_MIPStartEffort.html?view=kc

at least one of them should work without producing errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is as follows:

```
IloCplex::MIPStartEffort effort = IloCplex::MIPStartSolveFixed;
```

Notice the extra `IloCplex::` in front of `MIPStartSolveFixed`.